# Transform Matrix A to B through swapping elements

Tags: matrix, swap

Well, I got this homework where i must find the minimum number of swaps to convert some matrix A to other matrix B given, the constraints are very limited ("may not exceed 10 elements on the matrix and the matrix will also be N=M"), that means that it will be always a 1x1 matrix and a 2x2 matrix, (which is trivial), the problem is at the 3x3 matrix.

I already tried to backtrack the elements by seeking the manhattan distance between two elements on the matrix that are separated, multiply by two and substract - 1, e.g.

The rules of swapping are: You may swap elements that are adjacent, we define adjacent when they share the same row or the same column.

```
1 3 2

6 5 4

7 8 9
```

target:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

The manhattan distance between `{1,3}` is 1, so `2*1 - 1 = 1`, 1 swap needed.
for `{6,4}` is 2, so `2*2 - 1 = 3`, 3 swaps needed, then, the final answer is 4 swaps needed.

However, my program is getting rejected by the automatic corrector, any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: So the code is checked by the corrector, or just the result? If it's the code, are there any requirements stated you may have overlooked? (such as the using certain functions or language features)

Comment: Just the result, it's getting tested with like 10 different configurations, just 2 or 3 are getting correct results.